# How can i "activate" the port disabled/blocked by STP using OpenFlow and Ryu controller, so i could forward packets through it?

Tags: openflow, sdn, stp, ryu

I'm looking for the way to send packets using OpenFlow 1.3 protocol in SDN network in a topology with loop. My choice of controller is Ryu. To identify the hosts i'm catching ARP packets and to avoid floodstorm i'm using [STP](http://osrg.github.io/ryu-book/en/html/spanning_tree.html).

My problem is that when the path computed by my routing algorithm contains ports which are blocked/disabled by STP the connection can't be accomplished (hosts cannot ping each other).

After thinking it over i reached a conclusion that i need to "activate" disabled/blocked ports that are on my rounting path. But i cannot find any way to do that..

So now's the question: How can i achieve my solution? Is there any way to "activate" the ports in Ryu? Or if my solution is unachievable is there any other method i can use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

To activate a port you send an `ofp_port_mod` [message](http://ryu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ofproto_v1_3_ref.html#ryu.ofproto.ofproto_v1_3_parser.OFPPortMod) to the switch.

However, this will effectively disable STP, as you are opening up ports that may be part of a loop.

I think a better way of doing it might be for your routing algorithm to check if the port is disabled, by sending a `OFPMP_PORT_DESCRIPTION` [message](http://ryu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ofproto_v1_3_ref.html#ryu.ofproto.ofproto_v1_3_parser.OFPPortDescStatsRequest) to the switch and reading the `config` field in the reply. You can then treat those ports as being down and compute a different path (although I don't know if that's feasible in your case.)

Having said that, if I'm reading the openflow specs (section 7.2.1 Port Structures) correctly, you should still be able to route through a `BLOCKED` port, you just can't flood through it. This is different to a `DISABLED` port.

Comment: Good answer (vote up). Interesting, are you sure you can send non-flood messages through blocked ports ? Do you mind giving the version of openflow you were reading?

Comment: I think it's a good answer too. But, unfortunately, that was not feasible in my case. So i've decided not to use STP in my controller, but instead use a different approach. Good answer nonetheless, so vote up.

Comment: I was looking at openflow 1.3, as the original question stated.